# Displaying different jfree charts

Tags: java, combobox, jfreechart

I am trying to show scatter plot and  XYline chart using jfree chart. I am able to display them one at time. I have a combobox that lets you select type of plot you want to plot. On the basis of that i have to  plot the respective plot using jfree chart.

I have the following code to plot scatter plot and it works.

```
 JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Scatter Plot","Year","Production", dataset);
```

Now i have just added if statement and I have the following code that i have now used to plot as per users choice through combobox. It doesnot work. It simply says that variable chart is not used i.e. it doesnot recoginise variable chart outside if statement

```
if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Scatter Plot"))
                        {
                            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Scatter Plot","Year","Production", dataset);

                        }
                         if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Line Chart"))
                        {
                            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Line Chart","Year","Production", dataset);
                        }
```

My function for displaying the plot looks like this.

```
public void displayProduction() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

       XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
         XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Production");
        String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/data2";
    Connection conn;
    Statement stmt;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String USER = "root";
    String PASS = "";
        Object cropname = CropCombo.getSelectedItem();
       String cropnames = cropname.toString();
       Object locationname = LocationCombo1.getSelectedItem();
       String locationnames = locationname.toString();   
       Object yearfrom = yearfromCombo1.getSelectedItem();
       String yearfromcombo = yearfrom.toString();
       Object yearto = yeartoCombo1.getSelectedItem();
       String yeartocombo = yearto.toString();
       String pd="paddy ";
            System.out.println(cropnames.length()+" "+pd.length());

            System.out.println(cropsList);
         String sql;
         String sql1;
          sql1="Select * from production AS cust INNER JOIN location AS comp ON cust.location_id=comp.location_id INNER JOIN crops AS crop ON cust.crop_id=crop.crop_id WHERE comp.name=? AND crop.name=? AND year_of_production BETWEEN "+yearfrom + " AND " + yearto;
        try{
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            //stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
                        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
                        ps.setString(1, locationnames);
                         ps.setString(2, cropnames);

                       System.out.println(sql1);    
                       ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        // ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);                      
                        while (rs.next()){

                            String yeartext = rs.getString("year_of_production");

                            String productiontext = rs.getString("production_amount");

                            double production = Double.parseDouble(productiontext);
                            double years = Double.parseDouble(yeartext);
                            series.add(years,production) ;

                            //dataset.addSeries(series);              
             }
                        dataset.addSeries(series);

                        graph1.removeAll();
                        if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Scatter Plot"))
                        {
                            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Scatter Plot","Year","Production", dataset);

                        }
                         if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Line Chart"))
                        {
                            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Line Chart","Year","Production", dataset);
                        }

                        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
                        graph1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                        graph1.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
                        graph1.add(chartPanel);
                        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
//                        p.setRangeGridlinePaint(blue);
                        graph1.updateUI();
                        System.out.println("Database created successfully...");

                }
           catch(SQLException se)
                {
                    //Handle errors for JDBC
                    System.out.println("Connect failed ! ");
                    se.printStackTrace();
//                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MajorUI.this, err.getMessage());
                    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Local variables (including formal parameters) are visible only in the method, constructor, or block in which they are declared.**

> All local variables are effectively private to the block in which they are declared. No part of the program outside of the block can see them.

You have this code:

```
if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Scatter Plot"))
   {
   JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Scatter Plot","Year","Production", dataset);
   }
if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Line Chart"))
   {
   JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Line Chart","Year","Production", dataset);
   }
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
```

You declare `chart` inside the scope of the `if` block and then try to use it later when it is out of scope after the `if` block.

Try the following code:

```
JFreeChart chart;
if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Scatter Plot"))
   {
   chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Scatter Plot","Year","Production", dataset);
   }
if(jComboBox6.getSelectedItem().equals("Line Chart"))
   {
   chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Line Chart","Year","Production", dataset);
   }
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
```

See [Local/Instance/Class Variables](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/variables/45local-inst-class.html) for more information